# How to Create a EAMCET RAnk estimator and fetch data to show estimated rank using mysql php

Tags: php, html, mysql

I have to Combine Intermediate Marks + EAMCET Marks = Score

With that Score value how to fetch a Rank from using mysql php..
 This is my code

after getting the percentage scores, based on that scores i want fetch data using mysql php

Any Help Appreciated ..

```js
<script type="text/javascript">
function addNumbers() { var val1 = parseInt(document.getElementById("value1").value); var val2 = parseInt(document.getElementById("value2").value); var ansD = document.getElementById("rank"); ansD.value = (val1*(25/600)) + (val2*(75/160)); }
</script>
```

```html
  
<form action="/" method="post">
<table>
<tbody align="center">
<tr>
<th colspan="2">
<h1>EAMCET 2015 Engineering/Medical Rank Estimator</h1>
</th>
</tr>
<tr class="marks" style="font-weight: bold; background: whitesmoke;">
<td colspan="2"></td>
</tr>
<tr class="marks" style="font-weight: bold;">
<td>Enter your Intermediate Group Marks</td>
<td><input id="value1" maxlength="3" name="value1" size="10" type="text" value="" /></td>
</tr>
<tr class="marks" style="font-weight: bold">
<td>Enter your EAMCET Expected Marks</td><td><input type="text" id="value2" name="value2" value="" size="10" maxlength="3" onkeyup="javascript:addNumbers()"/></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td class="MsecNote" colspan="2"><b>Note:</b>* Intermediate group marks should be less than 600(1st &amp; 2nd Year)
* EAMCET marks should be less than 160. Your combined score will be calculated automatically.</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td colspan="2"><span class="marks">Your Combined Score (EAMCET WT + INTER WT) is
<input id="rank" name="rank" type="text" />
</span></td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td><input id="eamcet_0" type="radio" name="eamcet" value="Engineering" checked="checked" /><label for="eamcet_0">Engineering</label></td>
 <td><input id="eamcet_1" type="radio" name="eamcet" value="Medicine" /><label for="eamcet_1">Medicine</label></td>
 </tr>

 <tr>
        <td colspan="2" valign="top" style="text-align: center">
        <input type="submit" name="Button1" value="Submit" onclick="javascript:WebForm_DoPostBackWithOptions(new WebForm_PostBackOptions(&quot;Button1&quot;, &quot;&quot;, true, &quot;&quot;, &quot;&quot;, false, false))" id="Button1" class="Sbutton" />
        
  </td>
    </tr>
 <tr>
     <td colspan="2">
        <span id="ranks_out" class="marks"></span>
        </td>
    </tr>
 </tbody>
</table>
</form>
```

id  rank    eamcet  rank1
    Edit    Delete  2   95.33   engineering 10
    Edit    Delete  1   96.33   engineering 20

Comment: What do you want exactly in mysql query??also provide table structure for that @Sriram

Comment: this is sql table column names id, rank, eamcet, i want to fetch data using third text field values through mysql php and get the Rank data from database through that score. if u want more  information  check this url.. u can get an idea ...[link] http://sakshieducation.com/EAM/rank.aspx [link]